# OpenERP XML RPC Execute work flow return false

Tags: c#, odoo, xml-rpc

I am using c# to execute workflow for an invoice and I am sending signal invoice_open and it always returns false. I don't know why this happens. Can someone help me to fix this error?

Comment: You need to make your question clearer by showing us the code you're working on, and what exactly doesn't work. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: Yes it's true that exec_workflow 

    print models.exec_workflow(
        dbname, uid, password, 'account.invoice', 'invoice_cancel', 13)
    #False
    print models.exec_workflow(
        dbname, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'order_confirm', 12)
    #Flase    But it's always do it's task